# DAX time intelligence functions with nested filters

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a data structure like this

```
DateRoll    Dataset Date    Value   Customer
Month   Online  1/1/2018    10  Cust1
Month   Online  2/1/2018    11  Cust1
Month   Online  3/1/2018    12  Cust1
Month   Online  4/1/2018    22  Cust1
Quarter Online  1/1/2018    33  Cust1
Quarter Online  4/1/2018    22  Cust1
```

I have to calculate previous quarter value, I tried different ways but it's not working

1 - Not returning any value.

```
CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR'[Value] ),
        DATEADD ( 'Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR'[Date].[Date], -1, QUARTER ),
        FILTER ( Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR, Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR[DateRoll] = "Quarter")
    )
```

2--Nested - Returning overall total

```
CALCULATE (
        CALCULATE (
            SUM ( 'Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR'[Value] ),
            DATEADD ( 'Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR'[Date].[Date], -1, QUARTER )
        ),
        FILTER ( Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR, Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR[DateRoll] = "Quarter" )
    )
```

3--Nested --Returning overall total

```
CALCULATE (
        CALCULATE (
            SUM ( 'Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR'[Value] ),
            FILTER ( Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR, Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR[DateRoll] = "Quarter" )
        ),
        DATEADD ( 'Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR'[Date].[Date], -1, MONTH )
    )
```

Tried `PREVIOUSQUARTER` function too, but its not returning any value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Echoing @steliok that a date dimension is the proper way to handle this; there are plenty of date table templates out there, and a date dimension will work with your data model. If you really really can't add to your data structure for some reason, this should work:

```
BaseValue = SUM ( 'Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR'[Value] )
```

```
PriorQuarter =
VAR CurrentDate = MAX ( 'Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR'[Date] )
VAR CurrentYear = YEAR ( CurrentDate )
VAR CurrentMonth = MONTH ( CurrentDate )
VAR FirstMonthOfCurrentQuarter =
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        CurrentMonth IN {1,2,3}, 1,
        CurrentMonth IN {4,5,6}, 4,
        CurrentMonth IN {7,8,9}, 7,
        CurrentMonth IN {10,11,12}, 10
    )
// DATE() does the right thing with negative month args
VAR PriorQuarterDate = DATE ( CurrentYear, FirstMonthOfCurrentQuarter - 3, 1 )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        [BaseValue],
        ALL ( 'Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR'[DateRoll], 'Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR'[Date] ),
        'Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR'[Date] = PriorQuarterDate,
        'Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR'[DateRoll] = "Quarter"
    )
```

This relies on `DATE` being clever, which it is. `DATE ( 2019, -2, 1 ) = DATE ( 2018, 10, 1 )`.

Ultimately, my question is why can't you just source the un-rolled up data from the same place that the ETL process is sourcing it?

Comment: Thank you. This is a very special case I have, I have to provide drill-down (Y/Q/M) in the frontend visual, but shouldn't roll up in the frontend as these values are actual KPIs with some complex calculations.

Comment: My findings - if dates are not continuous, then DATEADD will work with .[Date] suffix to date column, like 'Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR'[Date].[Date]

Comment: to simplify this approach, I added PriorQuarterDate to date dimension and rewrote DAX function like this, but it's not working
CALCULATE (
            SUM ( 'Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR'[Value] ),
            FILTER('Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR','Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR'[Date]=FIRSTDATE(DateDim[PriorQuarterDate ])),
            FILTER(ALL('Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR'[DateRoll]),'Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR'[DateRoll]="Quarter")

Comment: If you've got a date dimension tied to your fact, then you want to do your filtering all on the date dimension:

`VAR PQDate = FIRSTDATE ( 'DateDim'[PriorQuarterDate] )
RETURN
  CALCULATE (
    ...
    ALL ( 'DateDim' ),
    'DateDim'[Date] = PQDate
)
`

When dims exist, filter only on the dims. And, in general, you'll have better performance with `CALCULATE ( ..., ALL ( 'Dim' ), 'Dim'[Field] = <literal> )` than doing a `FILTER ( 'Dim', ... )` or a `FILTER ( ALL ( 'Dim' ), ... )`.

Comment: And regarding KPI rollup, I strive to be a pragmatist first. If it's hard to build the KPIs and they're working, then roll with what you've got. Your question here, though, is indicating that what you've received is not working for you (else you wouldn't have a question). Maybe this was the only issue you had, in which case keep rolling with what you've got. At a certain point, you'll have to make the call if it's harder to work with weirdly shaped source, or if it's harder to implement your aggregates against transactional facts.

Comment: @greggby I completely agree. I have already started redesigning the model. Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

To take advantage of built in DAX time intelligence functions you will need to to have a contiguous set of dates. I would recommend using a date table. The following code can be used to create a date/calendar table in your model:

```
Celndar = 
Var MinDate = MIN(Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR[Date])
Var MaxDate = MAX(Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR[Date])
Var BaseCalendar = CALENDAR(MinDate, MaxDate)
RETURN
    GENERATE (
        BaseCalendar,
        VAR BaseDate = [Date]
        VAR YearDate =
            YEAR ( BaseDate )
        VAR MonthNumber =
            MONTH ( BaseDate )
        VAR YrMonth =
            100 * YEAR ( BaseDate )
                + MONTH ( BaseDate )
        VAR Qtr =
            CONCATENATE ( "Q", CEILING ( MONTH ( BaseDate ) / 3, 1 ) )
        RETURN
            ROW (
                    "Day", BaseDate,
                    "Year", YearDate,
                    "Month Number", MonthNumber,
                    "Month", FORMAT ( BaseDate, "mmmm" ),
                    "Year Month", FORMAT ( BaseDate, "mmm yy" ),
                    "YrMonth", YrMonth,
                    "Qtr", Qtr
            )
    )
```

Once this table exists, mark it as a 'date' table and create a relationship with

```
Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR[Date]
```

Then, you can write the following measure to obtain the results you are searching for:

```
PQSum =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR'[Value] ),
    PREVIOUSQUARTER ( 'Calendar'[Date] )
)
```

Hope that helps!

*Edited

You can also create a ranking column to index in a measure:

```
Rank =
RANKX (
    FILTER (
        'Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR',
        'Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR'[DateRoll] = EARLIER ( 'Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR'[DateRoll] )
    ),
    'Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR'[Date].[Date],
    ,
    ASC
)
```

Then you can reference a previous quarter using something like the following:

```
PQSum2 =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR'[Value] ),
    FILTER (
        'Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR',
        'Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR'[Rank]
            = MAX ( 'Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR'[Rank] ) - 1
    ),
    'Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR'[DateRoll] = "Quarter"
)
```

but this is hard coded and just plain nasty!

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I tried as you suggested. Its working fine withour the filter ,
        FILTER ( Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR, Data_Rollup_KPI_DNR[DateRoll] = "Quarter"), but with this filer its not working

Comment: @Gokul is there a reason you are using this [DateRoll] field instead of the calendar table quarter field?

Comment: yes, these are values are averages, they are rolled up separately at M/Q/Y in ETL layer

Comment: I see... then the calendar table may not be of much use to you. You could create a calculated column where you rank each category [DateRoll] by [Dataset Date] and then just use the rank as an index so to speak.

Comment: @Gokul see my edits... I would highly recommend you restructure your model

Comment: Thank you for the edits. I will use this as the last resort. Still wondering why DATEADD is not working with another FILTER condition!

Comment: @Gokul the reason is that you date set is not contiguous. Since filter is changing the context within the calculate statement it breaks the time intelligence.

Answer (score 1):

Date functions are working well when you are using @ Day level.

Following link would be helpful to resolve your issue,

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Lead-and-Lag-in-DAX/td-p/649162